# Multiple arguments in user-literals

Tags: c++, c++11

I've found this example on cppreference.com:

```
// used as conversion
inline constexpr long double operator"" _deg ( long double deg )
{
    return deg*3.141592/180;
}
...
double x = 90.0_deg; // x = 1.570796
```

But now I want to know, if I can give multiple arguments to that function. Here it is only `deg`. I mean something like that: `0.3_arg1_21arg2`

Comment: nope, there's room for a single suffix only, in the syntax

Comment: Interesting concept, slightly reminiscent of Objective-C’s method call syntax.

Comment: With units I would replace `_` with `*` to make it work (except for degrees Fahrenheit/Celsius, but these are not real units).

Answer (score 7):

This feature does’t exist – but you can emulate it!

For instance, you can make the following syntax work:

```
auto result = 0.3_arg1/21_arg2;
```

The `/` can be replaced by any overloadable operator of your choosing – maybe `,` would be a good choice, but beware of its low precedence. I would stick to something with a high precedence to ensure that this is parsed as if it were *one* literal (even though it isn’t).

Then, to make this work, you’d implement something like this (compiled in my brain only, so no guarantee of correctness):

```
struct value_proxy_lhs { double d; };
struct value_proxy_rhs { double d; };
struct final_value { double a; double b; };

inline constexpr value_proxy_lhs operator ""_arg1(double d) { return {d}; }

inline constexpr value_proxy_rhs operator ""_arg2(double d) { return {d}; }

inline constexpr final_value operator /(value_proxy_lhs lhs, value_proxy_rhs rhs) {
    return {lhs.d, rhs.d};
}
```

In a proper application you’d probably hide the `value_proxy_*` classes as much as possible from the users so that they cannot accidentally produce incomplete values. – Unfortunately, I don’t think there’s a way of avoiding this completely. For instance, the language simply doesn’t offer a way of forbidding something like `auto x{1_arg1};` to compile, as far as I know. Making the copy constructor `private` (and `final_value` a `friend`) would probably make the proxy classes non-POD and thus forbid using them as `constexpr` (AFAIR).

As a real-world application I could imagine a date “literal”:

```
auto date = 2013_yy/12_mm/07_dd;
```

Comment: *"Making the copy constructor `private` (and final_value a friend) would probably make the proxy classes non-POD and thus forbid using them as constexpr (AFAIR)."* `constexpr` only requires *literal types*. [basic.types]/10 defines *literal type*; one of the requirements for *literal type* is: "it is an aggregate type or has at least one `constexpr` constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor" I think it should be fine if the used ctors are `constexpr`.

Comment: My brain compiler says: error, cannot convert `value_proxy_lhs` to `double` in line `return {lhs, rhs};` (with lots of colours, arrows and squiggly underlining ;). Did you mean `return {lhs.d, rhs.d};`? Btw I think you could `delete` the copy ctor as well, and take the proxies by rvalue-ref (to make the intent clearer) or const lvalue-ref.

Comment: @DyP Sounds good. I’m too  busy now to test it rigorously but I’ll at least fix the compilation error. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news!

Comment: Why should the lack of direct language support stop us?  This is C++, where libraries can fake new language features.